# Comparison between Big Data and Data Lakes , difference and similarities

Tags: bigdata, data-science, data-lake

Can someone tell me the similarities and differences between Big data and Data Lakes.

Can't find a satisfactory answer anywhere.

Comment: Questions on stackoverflow need to be very specific. Broad questions like this will usually get downvoted and closed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think, We can't compare and differentiate both of them terminology because data lake is synonyms of the big data. Data lake = Enterprise data+ unstructured data + semi structure data.

Other hand it's data repository you can store any kind of data and used for analysis purpose. Mostly data will be stored in Hadoop FileSystem (HDFS), where as under "big data", there is storage & some other processing technology involved.

Comment: @Shambhu_Nath: May you please elaborate in how far "data lake" and "big data" are synonyms?

Answer (score 2):

**Big Data** is a term used in very different ways, one might call it even a buzzword. Often times, it is used as a collective term for digital technologies, [digitization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digitization), [industry 4.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Industry_4.0) and many topics connected with the digital transformation.

In the less general interpretation, big data simply refers to a complex, large dataset. The term "big" then refers to the three dimensions (see [Wikipedia on Big Data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_data))

1. *volume*, i.e. size of the data set
2. *velocity* at which the data volumes are generated
3. *variety* of data types and sources

A **Data Lake** refers to an *approach how to store big data*. Other possibilities of storing data are a traditional database also called *relational database management system (RDBMS)* on the one hand and a *data warehouse* on the other side, see for instance [Data Lake vs. Data Warehouse vs. Database: What’s The Difference?](https://www.bmc.com/blogs/data-lake-vs-data-warehouse-vs-database-whats-the-difference/)

Answer (score 0):

Big data and data lake are two different things.
Data lake is a concept where you have all your data stored and easily accessible using different mechanism. Data lake can be maintained on s3 or redshift or any other storage platform.
Big data is a term used for processing large volume of data. Mostly it refereed with big data solutions like Hadoop, Spark.